# Matlab format number to fixed TOTAL width

Tags: matlab, number-formatting

I am writing a mesh smoother in Matlab for a particular CFD code. The requirements for the mesh data file are very strict, and so the number format must be very specific. The definition for one quadrilateral element is as follows (Where the 2nd row is the x coordinates and 3rd row is y coordinates).

```
    ELEMENT         14 [    1Q]    GROUP     0
   5.000000       10.00000       10.00000       5.000000    
   2.000000       2.000000       4.500000       4.500000
```

As you can see, each number takes up exactly 8 characters. Once the whole mesh has been passed through my smoother, I need to write the numbers back to a file. the closest I've gotten to this number format is with the following operator:

%#7.7g

I don't think I can use %f, as this specifies the number of digits after the decimal, which in my case varies (I have coordinates that go from less than one to over 100). the only issue that this operator is giving me is when I have numbers less than one, it only retains 7 sig figs, and the number ends up being 9 characters long; for example:

0.9313373

Does anyone know the correct operator, or have a workaround? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

### Single format spec:

If you can live with only 4 digit precision (decimal part after the `.`) out of your 8 characters, and if the mesh reading program can handle padding `0` (i.e. if it can read values like `007.2365` properly), then the simplest and quickest option is to use only the format specifier.

For example, let's define an input `a` with different order of magnitude:

```
a=[  1 234    7             ;
    12   2    0.123456789   ;...
     5   2.36 0.0024      ] ;
```

Your highest number is 234, so that leaves 4 digits for the fractional part. If you accept that precision for all the numbers in your Matrix, then you're all set with a simple instruction:

```
fmt='%08.4f %08.4f %08.4f\n'; %// hard coded format specifier
sprintf(fmt,a.')              %'// we transpose a to keep the same shape in the output since sprintf is column major.

ans =

001.0000 234.0000 007.0000
012.0000 002.0000 000.1235
005.0000 002.3600 000.0024
```

---

If you don't know in advance what will be the maximum order of magnitude of your data you can set the format specifier programmatically:

```
nDigitTotal = 8 ;
nmax = ceil( log10(max(a(:))) ) ;        %// max order of magnitude of numbers in "a"
f   = sprintf('%%0%d.%df',nDigitTotal,nDigitTotal-nmax-1) ; %// format spec for 1 number
fmt = [f '\t' f '\t' f '\n'] ;                              %// format spec for a line of 3 numbers
s = sprintf(fmt,a.')
```

Will give the same result as above. *Add a check to make sure there are no extreme values in your matrix which will eat your precision.*

---

### Individual format spec:

Lastly, if that precision and/or the leading zero do not work for you, you can resort to a more elaborate solution. I quite like the idea from excaza of setting a mask to specify the precision for each number. I'll produce my own version, very slightly different, which account for numbers at any precision and allow array output. However, if you end up using this solution give credit to excaza since he was the inspiration for this evolution:

```
a = a.' ;                             %'// transpose from beginning/ thats done
nDigitTotal = 8;                      %// Total number of characters
mask = nDigitTotal(ones(size(a))) ;   %// Create mask

nOrder = floor( log10(a) ) ;          %// find order of magnitude of each element in the matrix
mask = mask - nOrder.*(nOrder>0) -1 ; %// adjust mask according to "nOrder" (only for nOrder>0)


temp = [mask(:)';a(:)'];              %// Stack the vectors and weave them

f = '%7.*f' ;                         %// basic format spec
fmt = [f '\t' f '\t' f '\n'] ;        %// build your line
sprintf(fmt,temp)                     %// go for it
```

will give you:

```
ans =

1.0000000   234.00000   7.0000000
12.000000   2.0000000   0.1234568
5.0000000   2.3600000   0.0024000
```

---

note: replace the tabulation (`'\t'`) with normal whitespace (`' '`) in the format specifier separator depending on what your meshing software is expecting.

Comment: All very good options. Thanks for making mine more robust so I didn't have to :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the only workaround I could think of:

```
A = [1.12341234 .12341234 20.12341234 5 10];

% Create a precision mask
maxwidth = 8; % Max width, characters
mask = maxwidth(ones(size(A))) - 1; % Initialize mask, account for decimal
mask(A < 1) = maxwidth - 2;

% Stack the vectors and weave them
temp = [mask(:)';A(:)'];
temp = temp(:);

test = sprintf('%#7.*g ', temp);
```

Which returns:

```
test =

1.123412 0.123412 20.12341 5.000000 10.00000
```

It's an annoying extra step but we can utilize `sprintf`'s ability to take an asterisk in order to refer to an argument in the input list. Due to how my `sprintf` call and test case are set up, I wove the mask and data together so `sprintf` sees the precision specifier and data alternating. The `temp(:)` call isn't necessary, if you pass the original `temp` matrix to `sprintf` it will do the same thing since it reads the data column-major. I added it in so the behavior is more explicit.

How to formulate the `sprintf` call for your actual printing routine will depend on what you're doing, but this should at least help you on your way.

**Edit1**: To expand, what the above is doing is equivalent to:

```
a = sprintf('%#7.*g ', temp(1), temp(2));
b = sprintf('%#7.*g ', temp(3), temp(4));
c = sprintf('%#7.*g ', temp(5), temp(6));
d = sprintf('%#7.*g ', temp(7), temp(8));
e = sprintf('%#7.*g ', temp(9), temp(10));

test = [a b c d e];
```

**Edit2**: Updated to account for integer values

**Edit3**: Note that this currently will only work for positive numbers

Comment: good idea about the mask and the argument of `sprintf`, but you should rework your format specifier. Your current solution only works if all the numbers are decimal. For `A=[12 , 2 , 0.123457]` this gives: `12       2 0.123457`

Comment: Nice, you get my vote, for a nice idea (_and also because I reused your idea_)

Comment: Very clever - I had not heard of `*`.